# in Java, what is the difference between the default package and another one?

Tags: eclipse, package

Creado una nueva clase con Eclipse, recibo este mensaje:

[image: Eclipse's message]

Is that just an Eclipse way of coordinating clases or is it a Java something? in that case... what does it mean to be in the default package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just saying you should organize your classes into meaningful named package instead of leaving it in the default package. Something like dont put all your files in the default folder where u start from. Make folders n organize them